# Proof of logical statement using induction

Tags: logic, induction, solution-verification

I've been struggling for a whole day with this proof in " discrete mathematics and its applications " by Rosen. I even found a solution online on sladder but wasn't conviced ( 90% the proof on sladder is correct and i just didn't get it ) . However i just came up with a proof but it's nothing like the one online so i wanted to share with more experienced people to check if the proof is indeed correct.(ps: the question is after induction is explained so we're supposed to use induction )

question:

[image]

My proof:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for induction (and fortunately not even a big urge to make all those "$\ldots$" rigorous).
In order to show
$$ \color{red}{[(p_1\to p_2)\land\cdots\land (p_{n-1}\to p_n)]}\to[\color{green}{(p_1\land\cdots \land p_{n-1})}\to\color{blue}{p_n}]$$
We *assume* the red part and show the gren/blue part, which again means that we assume the green part and show the blue part.
So assume "red". As it is of the form "something and $p_{n-1}\to p_n$", we have
$$ p_{n-1}\to p_n.$$
Next form assuming "green", which is of the form "something and $p_{n-1}$, we have
$$ p_{n-1}.$$
Now by modus ponens,
$$p_n, $$
as desired.

---

For  a similar statment that can be proved by induction, try
$$ \color{red}{[(p_1\to p_2)\land\cdots\land (p_{n-1}\to p_n)]}\to[\color{green}{p_1}\to\color{blue}{p_n}]$$